# How to test spring controller method using Junit

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, junit, junit4, junit3

Hi I'm new to Spring and to Junit as well. I have a method in my controller. I want to write Junit for this method (getPersons()).

```
@Autowired
private PersonService personService;

@RequestMapping(value="/t2/{yy_id}/person", method=RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public PersonInfo[] getPersons() {

    return personService.getPersons();
}
```

Can someone please help me and guide me in a right manner. Please give some example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should use the [mvc test framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework). It allows you to test all the mvc infrastructure - e.g. the `@RequestMapping`, `@ResponseBody` etc... - around your controller in addition to your own collaborators.

A very simple example of using the framework would be invoking the `getPersons()` method and asserting a `200` response code is received:

```
...
@Test
public void getPersons() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/t2/1234/person"))
      .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
...
```

The framework is capable of much more but I urge you to read the documentation, there are plenty of examples included. I hope that helps.

Comment: Hi Johnathan I agree with your answer and I have tried few things there but Still I'm facing some issues. I have updated my question can you tell me what wrong with it.

Comment: @Saurabh It would be better if you ask a new question. It's difficult to tell, however, ensure you have the correct static import declarations from `MockMvcResultMatchers` and `MediaType`. There are further [samples here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-mvc-showcase/tree/master/src/test/java/org/springframework/samples/mvc) that may help.